# Gradle compile time dependency version meaning of "+" in relation to remote repositories and caching

Tags: maven, dependencies, gradle

When using a "+" at the end of a compile time dependency version number in Gradle, what is the exact meaning of the "+" in relation to remote repositories and caching?

Specifically, the "+" signifies a dependency version of that number or greater. However, if I have a local version cached in Gradle and a version with a higher version number in a remote repository, which version will be chosen?

```js
repositories {
     maven { url 'www.example.com' }
}

dependencies {
     compile 'com.example.test:1.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle will cache the resolved version for a while (24 hours by default), then resolve again. Here is how you would reconfigure the timeout for all configurations in a project:

```
configurations.all.resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor(1, "hours")
```

For details, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html).